# Does Parental Support For Child In College Become Gifts When Child Files Independently?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax, dependents

Suppose the Child in College pays 55% of her Support with her own funds.  Then Child cannot be claimed as a dependent on Parents' return.

So would the 45% of the her Support paid by Parents, less direct payment there-within to school (for tuition) and medical service providers (for medical expenses including insurance premium), now be counted as "gifts"?

To be more concrete, suppose Parents buy Child a sweater, would this be a gift now?

Edit: Further clarification:

This is for the normal situation where parents and child are all US tax residents living in US.

Also I know that IRS probably does not CARE. But I want to know the exact legal answer. Also, I am not asking about the annual exemption or lift-time exemption. I just want a precise black and white answer --- is this a gift or not. (If on the other hand, Child paid less than 50% of her support and thus CAN BE CLAIMED AS A DEPENDENT, then buying her a sweater would be paying for her Support. Even if such sweaters add up to more than $30K, there is no relevance to gift/estate taxes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, excluding tuition paid directly and medical/premiums paid directly, this support would be considered [gift support](https://blog.taxact.com/gift-tax-supporting-adult-children/):

> You can pay as much as you want for tuition, medical expenses, or
> health insurance premiums on behalf of your children without worrying
> about gift tax returns.
>
> Just make sure you pay the school, hospital, or other organization
> directly.

If it matters to you, [529 plan contributions](https://www.savingforcollege.com/grandparents/answer/paying-tuition-directly-avoids-gift-tax-so-why-use-a-529-plan) can transform more of the educational support into non-gift support.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I found out as well.  Even thought IRS won't care about parents buying sweaters for kids, the problem is that: the implicit existence of sweaters (i.e. 45% support paid by parents) prevents parents from making a full $30K cash/securities transfer to child's investment account, without filing F709 and using the life-time exemption amount.   --- Hence my question.

Comment: Also, look into superfunding a 529 plan: https://www.savingforcollege.com/article/6-year-gift-tax-averaging

Answer (score 0):

The "IRS doesn't care" gift giving limit is $15000 per giver per year.

Thus, if you and the other parent are giving an amount close to $30000, then *technically* the gift might push you all over the $30000, but honestly the IRS won't care unless it's an *EXPENSIVE high-fashion* sweater.

---

Comment: Thank you.  I know that IRS probably does not CARE.  But I want to know the exact legal answer.  Also, I am not asking about the annual exemption or lift-time exemption.   I just want a precise black and white answer --- is this a gift or not.  (If on the other hand, Child paid less than 50% of her support and thus CAN BE CLAIMED AS A DEPENDENT, then buying her a sweater would be paying for her Support. Even if such sweaters add up to more than $30K, there is no relevance to gift/estate taxes.)

Comment: @ShangZhang if you want "the exact legal answer", then ask a tax accountant, not random strangers on the internet.